# OAuth2 refresh token utility

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm reading through the OAuth2 [RFC 6749 specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) before implementing an Authorization/Resource server for the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant.

I understand that the Client application uses the ***refresh_token*** (along with its credentials) to obtain a new access token for an End User (Resource Owner) rather than storing the End User's username/password and sending them every time an access_token expires.

However, to me this sounds like the refresh_token is as good as an access_token, it's pretty much just an extra server call, so why not use it directly i.e. if the refresh token is valid grant access?

Am I also correct to assume there is one refresh token per End User's session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, to me this sounds like the refresh_token is as good as an
>   access_token, it's pretty much just an extra server call, so why not
>   use it directly i.e. if the refresh token is valid grant access?

Because that extra server call to the Authorisation Server is important in ensuring access is still allowed to the client app. The resource server would not be able to verify that the refresh token is still good without talking to the Authorisation Server. But this is not the concern of the resource server.

A valid access token is a *bearer* token. It is used directly on the resource server to get data - no questions asked. If it's not expired, and it has the right scopes - here's the data, whoever you are!

A refresh token on the other hand has to be presented to the Authorisation Server along with client credentials. The Authorisation Server may choose to verify that the resource owner hasn't revoked access to that client, or that the client app itself is still valid. If OK the authorisation server can mint a new, short-lived bearer access token, which is as good as data to anyone who has it!

Comment: This makes sense, but in my case, the Authentication and Resource servers are the same, and I have only one trusted Client App that cannot be revoked, at least not by an End User.